# Errors in a class when trying to call it

Tags: python, class, object, subclass, ode

I have this code consisting of a class and a subclass. The class is Euler forward, while the second one is Eulers midpoint method. These are for solving an ODE (x'=x(1/2-x)). Now it doesn't seem to work because when I am to call the function, by typing:

> Euler=H.solve(6)

where the 6 is the amount of steps, I get attributeerror.

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'size'
```

Could anyone help me make my code more robust and working so I could plot the values later on, really don't see whats wrong. My code below:

```
import numpy as np    


class H:
    def __init__(self, f):
        self._f = f

    def initial(self, u0):
        self._u0 = u0

    def solve(self, time_points):
        n = time_points.size
        self._t = time_points
        self._u = np.zeros(n)
        self._u[0] = self._u0
        for k in range(n-1):
            self._k = k
            self._u[k+1] = self.advance()
        return self._u, self._t


class F(H):
    def ad(self):
        u = self._u; t = self._t; f = self._f; k = self._k
        dt = t[k+1] - t[k]
        u_k12 = u[k] + dt/2 * f(u[k], t[k])
        return u[k] + dt * f(u_k12, (t[k] + dt/2) )
```

Comment: In `solve` you make `_k`, `_t` and `_u` permanent class members without needing to. You could keep them as temporary, local variables if you changed the interface of `advance(self)` to `advance(self,u,t,dt)`. It also makes little sense to return the unchanged parameter `time_points` in `self._t`.

Answer (score 1):

I think what's wrong is the way you use the class. Initial value is set with `initial`  method (u0), then you give `solve` method the list of points. You can use `np.linscape` to generate *midpoint*.

```
np.linspace(0, 3, 31)  # 30 points evenly spaced between 0 and 3
```

So it's like this:

```
def func(x, y):
    return x * y

midpoint = np.linspace(0, 3, 31)

F_ = F(func)
F_.initial(6)
F_.solve(midpoint)
```

Code:

```py
class H:
    def __init__(self, f):
        self._f = f

    def initial(self, u0):
        self._u0 = u0

    def solve(self, time_points):
        n = time_points.size
        self._t = time_points
        self._u = np.zeros(n)
        self._u[0] = self._u0

        for k in range(n-1):
            self._u[k+1] = self.advance(k)

        return self._u, self._t

    def advance(self, k):
        ....


class F(H):
    def advance(self, k):
        dt = self._t[k+1] + self._t[k]
        u_k12 = self._u[k] + dt/2 * self._f(self._u[k], self._t[k])
        return self._u[k] + dt * self._f(u_k12, (self._t[k] + dt/2))
```

Comment: When I do that I get error: self._u[0] = self._u0

AttributeError: 'H' object has no attribute '_u0'

Comment: Initialize `self.u0` inside `__init__`

Comment: Then I get error: self._u[0] = self._u0

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Comment: I do the exact same thing, but do def F(t):
    return np.exp(t/2)/(2*np.exp(t/2)-1)

midpoint = np.linspace(0, 3, 6)

H_ = H(F)
H_.initial(6)
H_.solve(midpoint)

Comment: Then I get error TypeError: F() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given which makes no sens @yudaka

Comment: please help me i rly need this

Comment: You might want to use a difference for the time increment.